# Can't start laravel-echo-server with supervisor

Tags: linux, laravel, socket.io, supervisord, laravel-echo

I have already referenced all of the other suggestions that people have made on other posts, nothing has worked.

## Paths to Relevant Files

The root directory of my project is `/var/www/html` and that is where I have `.env` and `laravel-echo-server.json`.

I have laravel-echo-server installed globally. I can run it successfully from a with `laravel-echo-server start --dir=/path/to/project/root`

When I run `which laravel-echo-server`, it shows its path is `~/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/bin/laravel-echo-server`.

Likewise, the path for node is `~/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/bin/node`

My conf file for the supervisor worker is at `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-echo-server.conf`.

Supervisor runs the other workers successfully, such as Horizon, so it is not a problem with the supervisor configuration.

## Conf File

```
[program:laravel-echo-server]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html
autostart=true
numprocs=1
user=root
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/workers/laravel-echo-server.log
```

I have also tried the following variations for the command line:

```
command=/usr/bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html
command=~/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/bin/laravel-echo-server --dir=/var/www/html
```

All of these attempts and variations return `ERROR (no such file)`.

I also tried making duplicate copies of laravel-echo-server.json to place in locations like `/usr/bin` and `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` but that didn't help.

I also tried changing the user from `root` to `ec2-user` (which is my username with which I can successfully initialize laravel-echo-server from the command line).

I have also tried adding another line: `directory=/var/www/html` but that doesn't help.

## Shell Executable Attempt

I tried to make a shell executable file that supervisor could call. Here is the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec laravel-echo-server start --dir=../../../var/www/html
```

I called the executable with supervisor like this:

```
command=bash -c laravel-echo-server.sh
```

But it returned `ERROR (spawn error)`.

## Additional Info

#### supervisord.conf

```
[inet_http_server]
port=*:9001

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisord]
;http_port=/var/tmp/supervisor.sock ; (default is to run a UNIX domain socket server)
;http_port=127.0.0.1:9001  ; (alternately, ip_address:port specifies AF_INET)
;sockchmod=0700              ; AF_UNIX socketmode (AF_INET ignore, default 0700)
;sockchown=nobody.nogroup     ; AF_UNIX socket uid.gid owner (AF_INET ignores)
;umask=022                   ; (process file creation umask;default 022)
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10          ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info               ; (logging level;default info; others: debug,warn)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false              ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                 ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)

;nocleanup=true              ; (don't clean up tempfiles at start;default false)
;http_username=user          ; (default is no username (open system))
;http_password=123           ; (default is no password (open system))
;childlogdir=/tmp            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
;user=chrism                 ; (default is current user, required if root)
;directory=/tmp              ; (default is not to cd during start)
;environment=KEY=value       ; (key value pairs to add to environment)

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock
;serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001 ; use an http:// url to specify an inet socket
;username=chris              ; should be same as http_username if set
;password=123                ; should be same as http_password if set
;prompt=mysupervisor         ; cmd line prompt (default "supervisor")

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

#### laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": http://mywebsite.com,
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {[my redis credentials]},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

Now I have tried:

```
command=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html
```

per the suggestion in the post comments. However that is returning `ERROR (spawn error)`

When I check the supervisord.log, it shows the following:

```
2019-12-31 07:27:05,869 INFO exited: laravel-echo-server_00 (exit status 127; not expected)
```

Exit status code 127 apparently means "command not found".

Comment: `~` is shorthand for user home directory (e.g. `/home/<username>/`) so try: `command=/home/<username>/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/bin/laravel-echo-server` since supervisor usually runs with a different home

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks thats a great tip! However I got ERROR (spawn error). It doesn't really give me any logs to go on and I can't figure out from the supervisor docs what spawn error means

Comment: Running `/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v13.5.0/bin/laravel-echo-server start --dir=/var/www/html` directly in the command line does work.

Comment: I don't know what else could be wrong. Maybe just bite the bullet and use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for this particular thing

Comment: My thoughts exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after giving up on running it with composer, it became easiest to run it with pm2.

Here is my .ebextensions command:

```
sudo yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_13.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo yum install -y nodejs
npm config set scripts-prepend-node-path true
npm install -g laravel-echo-server
npm install -g pm2@latest
pm2 start laravel-echo-server-pm2.json
```

And my pm2 json:

```
{
  "name": "laravel-echo-server",
  "script": "laravel-echo-server",
  "args": "start"
}
```

I also added a few more commands to .ebextensions that allow me to modify my .env file. The changes overwrite the values written into laravel-echo-server.json. This way, I don't have to change them every time I switch from dev to prod:

```
echo "LARAVEL_ECHO_SERVER_REDIS_HOST=production-redis-host.com" >> .env
echo "LARAVEL_ECHO_SERVER_REDIS_PORT=6379" >> .env
echo "LARAVEL_ECHO_SERVER_DEBUG=false" >> .env
```